# How to resolve chrome driver crashing after 3 to 5 minutes

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, crash, selenium-chromedriver

I have been facing an issue with chrome driver, which is automatically crashing after running 5 minutes. we are utilizing chrome driver 79.0.39 version and chrome browser 79.0.39 version.

we running the program as service and we can see the crashed file in below location

Running as service: systemctl start filename.service

Path where I can see crashed file .dmp /tmp/systemd-private-aa11223322333abc1b11ab1111cc11dd-filename.service-*/tmp

Here is my sample code

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
prefs={'disk-cache-size': 4096 }
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get(url_frame)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
res = json.loads(soup.find("body").text)
try:
    driver.close()
except Exception as e:
    print(" Exception while closing driver ")

try:
    driver.quit()
except Exception as e:
    print(" Exception while quit driver ")
```

Note: We are not running chrome driver or selenium with admin

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does the **crashed file** says?

Comment: It is showing below message

 (WebDriverException("unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed\n  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)\n  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)", None, None),)